# Sendgrid template: email body is hidden in gmail

Tags: gmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have created transactional template in Sendgrid using HTML code editor. While testing it using my gmail, I noticed that gmail hides email body and I need to click on 3 dots icon button to see that hidden part:

[image]

Does anyone know why it is happening and how can I fix it in my send grid template?

Comment: Can you share the code you have written?

Comment: Did you ever find the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: @ateymour, unfortunately not. I didn't find solution for this one.